# How to remote debug a java based service running in openshift cluster of type ClusterIP?

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift, remote-debugging

I am trying to remote debug a java based service running on OCP cluster of type ClusterIP.

I have tried steps from https://blog.openshift.com/debugging-java-applications-on-openshift-kubernetes/.
But none of these are working.
By changing type of service from ClusterIP to NodePort, i am able to remote debug.

Comment: hi, as the docs say, you can attach the pod running on openshift to your localhost `oc port-forward <pod_name> PORT:PORT # Replace <pod_name> with the value from the previous step`

Comment: `ClusterIP` is required `route` object to access from external points basically, but `route` is available to `HTTP`, `HTTPS`, `Web socket` and `TLS` through `router` haproxy pod. So I think `nodeIP` is no problem as alternatives, if debugs tools supports other protocols, such as TCP. `nodeIP` can support `TCP` protocols.